# Sliding Horizontal responsive Layout and MouseWheel input

Tags: jquery, css, layout

I'm trying to implement a **sliding horizontal layout** with a header banner.

This is the HTML structure:

```
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <div><a href="#one"> one </a></div>
    <div><a href="#two"> two </a></div>
    <div><a href="#thr"> thr </a></div>
  </div>

  <div id="one" class="panel"> </div>
  <div id="two" class="panel"> </div>
  <div id="thr" class="panel"> </div>
</body>
```

The header is fixed, and panels have been provided with a gradient background (middle panel has a different color for debug purpose).
Here is the CSS:

```
    body {
      width: 6000px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .panel {
      width: 33.3%;
      float: left;
      padding-left: 30px;
      padding-right: 1040px;
      margin-top: -75px;
      height: 960px;
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0B88FF, #95EEFF);
    }

    #header {
      position: fixed;
      height: 75px;
      margin-top: 25px;
    }

    #two{
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0B8800, #9E5EFF);
    }
```

And finally the function which manages the animation between panels:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#header a").bind("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).attr("href");
    $("html, body").stop().animate({
      scrollLeft: $(target).offset().left,
      scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
    }, 1200);
  });
});
```

The problems I'm facing are the following:

1) I tried to implement a jQuery function to run the slide animation when user uses the mouse wheel, but none of my tests work...the structure is always the same:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
        var target // still not able to figure out who should i target
        $("html, body").stop().animate({
            //to the target >,<
       }
});
```

2) When my browser window is at 100% size everything seems to work well, but if I reduce or increase the zoom everything mess up >,<
I notice it is possible to handle this, and [here is an example:](http://www.unravelgame.com/)

Answer (score 2):

To get your targets you could just fill an array witj the element with `panel` class, and then use an index to move through the panels.

Finally, if you have problems with the scroll on window resize, you could bind this [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Events/resize) and do whatever you want

Take a look at [MouseWheelEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseWheelEvent).

And try this example with your code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#header a").bind("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).attr("href");
    $("html, body").stop().animate({
      scrollLeft: $(target).offset().left,
      scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
    }, 1200);
  });
  
  var scroll_targets = $(".panel");
  var scroll_targets_index = 0;
  $(window).on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function (e) {    
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
      if(scroll_targets_index < scroll_targets.length-1){
        var where = ++scroll_targets_index;
        $("html, body").stop().animate({
          scrollLeft: $(scroll_targets[where]).offset().left,
          scrollTop: $(scroll_targets[where]).offset().top
        }, 1200);
      }
    } 
    else {
     var where;
     if(scroll_targets_index > 0){
        where = --scroll_targets_index;
      }
      else{
       where = 0;
      }
       $("html, body").stop().animate({
          scrollLeft: $(scroll_targets[where]).offset().left,
          scrollTop: $(scroll_targets[where]).offset().top
        }, 1200);
      
    }
  });
  
  $(window).resize(function () {
    $('html,body').scrollTop($(scroll_targets[where]).offset().top);
    $('html,body').scrollLeft($(scroll_targets[where]).offset().left);
  });
});
```

```css
#body {
      width: 6000px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .panel {
      width: 33.3%;
      float: left;
      padding-left: 30px;
      padding-right: 1040px;
      margin-top: -75px;
      height: 960px;
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0B88FF, #95EEFF);
    }

    #header {
      position: fixed;
      height: 75px;
      margin-top: 25px;
    }

    #two{
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0B8800, #9E5EFF);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="body">
  <div id="header">
    <div><a href="#one"> one </a></div>
    <div><a href="#two"> two </a></div>
    <div><a href="#thr"> thr </a></div>
  </div>

  <div id="one" class="panel"> </div>
  <div id="two" class="panel"> </div>
  <div id="thr" class="panel"> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Unravel, I think this was made with CSS and JavaScript using transform3d and some other css tricks. If you want to get the scroll event, it will not happen while you have overflow:hidden on the body, because you just told the browser to hide all its scrolls ! So, what I tried to do to solve the problem you are having now, was to use the mousewheel event, which acts like this:

```
$(window).on('wheel', function (event) {      
    console.log(event); // Here you can see all of its events properties and functions in the console
});
```

There is a wheelDelta property which returns 120 if you are doing a mousewheel forward, or -120 when doing a mousewheel backward, so I attached a counter so that I could know how many times the mousewheel event triggered:

```
$(window).on('wheel', function (event) {      

    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0 ) {
        count++;
        console.log(count)  ;
        if(count > 30 ){

            $("html, body").stop().animate({
              scrollLeft: $('#two').offset().left,
              scrollTop: $('#two').offset().top
            }, 1200);   
        }
        if(count > 60 ){

            $("html, body").stop().animate({
              scrollLeft: $('#thr').offset().left,
              scrollTop: $('#thr').offset().top
            }, 1200);               
        }
        if(count > 90 ){

            $("html, body").stop().animate({
              scrollLeft: $('#two').offset().left,
              scrollTop: $('#two').offset().top
            }, 1200);   
            count = 0;          
        }


    }
});
```

This is only for you to continue creating the logic to build when the mousewheel will change to another panel and so on, good luck !